# Updating association without saving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B
end
```

And I want to reset or update A's B association, but only save it later:

```
a = A.find(...)
# a.bs == [B<...>, B<...>]
a.bs = [] 
#or
a.bs = [B.new, B.new]
# do some validation stuff on `a` and `a.bs`
```

So there might be some case where I will call `a.save` later or maybe not. In the case I don't call `a.save` I would like that `a.bs` stay to its original value, but as soon as I call `a.bs = []`, the old associations is destroyed and now `A.find(...).bs == []`. Is there any simple way to set a record association without persisting it in the database right away? I looked at Rails source and didn't find anything that could help me there.

Thanks!

Edit:

I should add that this is for an existing application and there are some architecture constraint that doesn't allow us to use the the regular ActiveRecord updating and validation tools. The way it works we have a set of `Updater` class that take params and assign the checkout object the value from `params`. There are then a set of `Validater` class that validate the checkout object for each given params. Fianlly, if everything is good, we save the model.

In this case, I'm looking to update the association in an Updater, validate them in the Validator and finally, persist it if everything check out.

In summary, this would look like:

```
def update
    apply_updaters(object, params)
    # do some stuff with the updated object
    if(validate(object))
        object.save(validate: false)
end
```

Since there are a lot of stuff going on between `appy_updaters` and `object.save`, Transaction are not really an option. This is why I'm really looking to update the association without persisting right away, just like we would do with any other attribute.

So far, the closest solution I've got to is rewriting the association cache (`target`). This look something like:

```
# In the updater
A.bs.target.clear
params[:bs].each{|b| A.bs.build(b)}
# A.bs now contains the parameters object without doing any update in the database
```

When come the time to save, we need to persist cache:

```
new_object = A.bs.target
A.bs(true).replace(new_object)
```

This work, but this feel kind of hack-ish and can easily break or have some undesired side-effect. An alternative I'm thinking about is to add a method `A#new_bs=` that cache the assigned object and `A#bs` that return the cached object if available.

Comment: AFAIK this has no sense because AR commits work to DB only for some explicit method calls. Are you sure that problem in `a.bs = []`? Can you debug around it and see exact SQL execution in log?

Comment: If you need the database to never fall into the state when the previous associations have been destroyed and new ones not saved yet: wrap your changes into a transaction. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AlkH From the [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference-when-are-objects-saved-questionmark): "When you assign an object to a has_many association, that object is automatically saved (in order to update its foreign key). If you assign multiple objects in one statement, then they are all saved."

I think this is what is happening to me

Comment: @D-side What I'm trying to do is to have an endpoint that takes a bunch of B and build them on A so I can do some validation on A and B afterward. If that validation fails, I don't want to assign the new Bs and I want to revert to the old one. I can't really use transaction because of the architecture behind all this. I would expect that just not calling `a.save` would be enough, but it seems from my test that just doing `a.bs = []` is destroying the current Bs.

Comment: I fail to see why. When you abort a transaction, all changes inside it are reverted. What's the problem?

Comment: Arn't Rails transaction locking the row and keeping that lock for too long can lead to performance issue or worse, dead lock?

Comment: @D-side Yeah, seems like transaction is pretty much the easiest way to keep the old association in place in case of error. I don't feel safe about this tho since there is a lot happening between the assignment and validation.

Comment: Transactions are not the best option because in your case AR really will perform `DELETE` query for all items in collection (my shame), then `INSERT` or rollback in any case. I recommend to use attributes assignment and regular validations (in this case AR touch only needed records). In answer I've tried to guide how to set it up. It's not direct answer, it's another solution, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out about the `mark_for_destruction` method. My final solution therefor look like:

```
a.bs.each(&:mark_for_destruction)
params[:bs].each{|b| a.bs.build(b)}
```

And then I can filter out the `marked_for_destruction?` entry in the following processing and validation.

Thanks @AlkH that made me look into how `accepts_nested_attributes_for` was working and handling delayed destruction of association.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.
I can advice to use attributes assignment instead of collection manipulation. All validations will be performed as regular - after `save` or another 'persistent' method. You can write your own method (in model or in separated validator) which will validate collection.

You can delete and add elements to collection through attributes - deletion is performed by additional attribute `_destroy` which may be 'true' or 'false'  (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), addition - through setting up parent model to accept attributes.

As example set up model A:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :b
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :b, :allow_destroy => true
   validates_associated :b # to validate each element

   validate :b_is_correct # to validate whole collection
   def b_is_correct
      self.bs.each { |b| ... } # validate collection
   end
end
```

In controller use plain attributes for model updating (e.g `update!(a_aparams)`). These methods will behave like flat attribute updating. And don't forget to permit attributes for nested collection.

```
class AController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @a = A.find(...)
    @a.update(a_attributes) # triggers validation, if error occurs - no changes will be persisted and a.errors will be populated
  end

  def a_attributes
    params.require(:a).permit([:attr_of_a, :b_attributes => [:attr_of_b, :_destroy]])
  end
end
```

On form we used gem nested_form (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), I recommend it. But on server side this approach uses attribute `_destroy` as mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `accepts_nested_attributes_for` looks interesting, I will take a look into that. One of the issue is that we are building the `B` object with a custom method, so I would need to find a way that `update(attributes)` end up calling the same build method.